# Installing ZF2 500 error with .htaccess 403 (Forbidden error) without .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, zend-framework2, apache2

I've been trying to set up ZF2, I have the directory set up in `/home/jack/instantpk/framework/` with the "public" directory containing the .htaccess and the index.php in that folder as `/home/jack/instantpk/framework/public/index.php | .htaccess`

I've configured my hosts so that:
`127.0.0.1       zf2.localhost.com`
is set.

I've also modified the `000-default.conf` file found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory so that it now reads

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName zf2.localhost.com
        ServerAlias zf2.localhost.com
        DocumentRoot /home/jack/instantpk/framework/public

   <Directory /home/jack/instantpk/framework/public>
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,Deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my .htaccess file located in `home/jack/instantpk/framework/public/`

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

If I remove the .htaccess file I get a 403 Forbidden error:
`You don't have permission to access /**** on this server.`

If that file exists I get a 500 error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Both errors occur when I try to visit `http://zf2.localhost.com/`

I've been fiddling around with this for a while now and nothing seems to be useful reading online - if anybody could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that mod rewrite was not enabled, I'd recently updated my apache version so the .htaccess was throwing a 500 error.

As for the 403 error - I'm not sure, I got around this by moving my directory into the /var/www folder

Quite silly mistakes on my part, hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as correct since it solves the problem.

Comment: You can't for 48 hours @foozy